# Checking a directory and matching with file

Tags: perl, file, directory

I want to look at a file called `missing` and then look within a directory called `flags`.

Every file listed in `missing` will always appear in the `flags` directory.

I want to look at every file in the `flags` directory and then see if they are in the `missing` file. If one of them is not, delete that file from the `flags` directory.

```
    @flags=`ls $dir`;
    $flags_size = scalar @flags;

    $file = "/home1/t01jkxj/check_st/missing";
    $filesize = -s $file;

    if ($filesize < $flags_size) {
      ##What to do??##
    }
```

Comment: Why do you compare the size of `$file` to the number of elements in the `@flags` array?

Comment: @TLP: I think it is clear to you that the OP doesn't understand the `-s` operator.

Comment: So you want to delete all files in a directory called `flags` that don't appear in a file called `missing`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't decribe the format of the `missing` file, but I guess it contains one file per line and gives the full absolute path to the files. You will need to adjust this solution if I have guessed incorrectly.

This program loads the `missing` file into a hash. Each hash element has the filename as its key and a value of 1.

The `flags` directory is opened, and the path is added to each of the file names to form an absolute path in `$filename`. The filename is printed if it doesn't appear in the `%missing` hash. To actually delete the file the `unlink` line should be uncommented.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $missing = "/home1/t01jkxj/check_st/missing";

open my $fh, '<', $missing or die qq(Unable to open "$missing" for read: $!);
my %missing;
while (<$fh>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  chomp;
  $missing{$_} = 1;
}

my $dir = '/path/to/flags';

opendir my $dh, $dir or die qq(Unable to open directory "$dir": $!);

for my $file (readdir $dh) {
  my $filename = "$dir/$file";
  unless ($missing{$filename}) {
    # unlink $filename;
    print qq(File "$filename" deleted as not found in 'missing' file\n);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out hashes.  Put all your entries from missing into a hash.  Then loop through all the files in the flags dir and check if it's in the hash.  If it is, fine, if not, delete the file.

```
my %missings = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } do {
  open my $fh, '<', $missing_file or die "Can't read $missing_file: $!";
  <$fh>
};

opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Can't read from $dir: $!";
while(readdir $dh) {
    unlink $_ unless delete $missings{$_};
}

# I know, you said this can't happen.
if (keys %missings) {
    print "The following are in $missing_file but not in $dir:\n";
    print "    $_\n" for sort keys %missings;
}
```

Warning: completely untested.  I typed this right into the box in my web browser.

Comment: Your warning is warranted. Your code will attempt to unlink both `.` and `..` (but it will hopefully fail, since unlink cannot normally delete directories), and in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not in Linux right now but this is sort of what you need to do. This script collects the listing of files in the file and in the array directory, then finds the difference of the two. I would test but can't really )-=. Consider it pseudocode!:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $fi;
my $line;
my @to_delete;
my $var;
my @indir;
my @files;
# the difference of @females and @simpsons
@indir = `ls`;

open($fi, "< list.txt");
while ($line = <$fi>) 
{
    chomp($line);
    push @files, $line;
}
@to_delete=grep(!defined $indir{$_}, @files); #gets difference of the two arrays


print "Delete this:\t$_\n" foreach (@to_delete);
```

Comment: You cannot use chomp like this: `push @files, chomp($line)`. `chomp` returns the total number of characters removed from its argument, not the argument itself. Also, you cannot grep like that, since you do not have any keys in the `%flags` hash.

Comment: Thanks - those are huge mistakes on my part. Let me know others. Or just edit such that it is correct, because I may take too many drafts heh.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you can do this with a bash command too. Something like:

```
cd /path/to/flags; ls | grep -vf missing.txt | xargs rm
```

NOTE: Please don't run the above without testing it.

In perl, it would probably be a good idea to be somewhat verbose in the code and issue a warning. Of course, the warnings can be removed for automated jobs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = "/path/to/flags";
chdir $dir or die $!;        # change working directory
my @flags = <*>;             # get a list of the files
my $file = "/home1/t01jkxj/check_st/missing";
open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
chomp(my @missing = <$fh>);  # get file names and remove newlines
my %missing = map { $_ => 1 } @missing;   # ..and put them in a hash

my @delete;
for my $file (@flags) {      # all files not in the hash go into @delete
    push @delete, $file unless $missing{$file};
}

if (@delete) {   # do not delete without confirmation
    print @delete . " files to delete\n@delete\n---\nDelete them all? ";
    my $reply = <>;
    if ($reply =~ /^y$/) {
        unlink $_ or warn "$_: $!" for @delete;
    }
} else {
    print "No missing files to delete.\n";
}
```